# builddeps:gawk : Depends: libreadline-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I'm doing

```
lz@blade:~$ sudo apt-get build-dep gawk
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 builddeps:gawk : Depends: libreadline-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

here's my sources:

```
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted


deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse main universe restricted

deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe


deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
```

What are the broken packages?

Comment: `libreadline-dev` is available for supported versions of Ubuntu https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libreadline-dev&searchon=names ... Solving "broken packages" : `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: @KnudLarsen but my version of ubuntu is supported, and `sudo apt install -f` changes nothing

Comment: @KnudLarsen  im on 18.04

Answer (score 0):

```
software-properties-gtk
```

Change download source to main server. `sudo apt update && sudo apt-get clean` and try again.

Forgot, and unlock for other sources `deb-src`